# Phoenix: is there a way to alias a view in another view?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

So I'm trying to **alias** a view in another view. But i was getting an error that the json I was calling cannot be rendered.

**employee_view**

```
alias AuthAppWeb.EdtrView

def render("employee_dtr.json", %{employee: employee}) do
%{
  id: employee.id,
  personal_info: employee.personal_info,
  edtr: render_one(employee.edtr, __MODULE__, "edtr.json", as: EdtrView)
}end
```

**edtr_view**

```
def render("edtr.json", %{edtr: edtr}) do
%{
  id: edtr.id,
  m_in: edtr.m_in,
  m_out: edtr.m_out,
  a_in: edtr.a_in,
  a_out: edtr.a_out,
  o_in: edtr.o_in,
  o_out: edtr.o_out,
  status: edtr.status,
  sub_status: edtr.sub_status,
  dtr_date: edtr.dtr_date
}end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument is supposed to be the view you are trying to call. You are currently calling `__MODULE__` which will expand to the module that is being called from. In your case, `EmployeeView`. What you will want is the following.

```
render_one(employee.edtr, EdtrView, "edtr.json")
```